# O que pode causar o erro na conversão do JSON?

Tags: json, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um crawler, que irá pegar os GIFS do 9gag. O código é esse:

```py
In [11]: import requests                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [12]: t = requests.get('https://9gag.com/v1/group-posts/group/gif/type/hot?')                                                                                                                                   

In [13]: t.json()
```

```
lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

ipython:
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Mas quando executo `print(t.json())`:

`*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 16134: ordinal not in range(128)`

O detalhe se eu executar `t.json()` dá tudo certo e o ipython imprime a conversão, mas usando print dá errado.

*Isso parece no meu terminal: `-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (pt_BR.UTF-8)`

Comment: Vinicius, verificou este link? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408252/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xbf-in-position-3

Comment: Isso aparece na meu terminal: `-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (pt_BR.UTF-8)`

Comment: voce tem erteza u o projto está rodando com o python 3.5, e não com o python2 do servidor?

Comment: sim, eu me certifiquei disso. está rodando em uma env